# Lasting spectral trace from funeral rites

Tags: stars, solar-system

So burial in space has been a thing in more sci-fi properties than I can count, and I've always wondered how long evidence of such a practice would last. In interstellar space there is little to disturb the funerary remains and they may last indefinitely but the chances of anyone noticing in the vastness of space are negligible. Maybe it's different if a civilisation is using a particular star as the resting place for it's honoured dead though. So if we're looking across the gulf of space at other stars is there anything we might notice about their emission spectra that would tip us off that something odd happened there in, cosmically, recent history.

In particular what elements from the body of a carbon based life form similar to a human might persist in the [Corona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_corona), [Chromosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosphere) or even deeper down in the [Photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere) of a star and show a detectable spectral trace? Not necessarily elements necessary to life but the full list of what we tend to absorb over a lifetime. What volume of material would need to have gone into the star for us to detect it and how long could such a signal be expected to last? I know for example that a strong trace of Lithium might point to "currently" (current when the star light we are seeing was emitted) active star dumping as Lithium is burned up in the stellar atmosphere but other elements that shouldn't be present may last longer.

If bodies won't leave a noticeable trace are there elements that might be deliberately dumped into a star and create a long lasting trace that says "we were here", whoever we is? That's deliberately dumped as waste not deliberately placed as a signal, sorry that was unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic issue here is precision. It's very hard to measure elemental abundances to the degree of accuracy that would be presumably required. I'm not a solar spectroscopist, but my understanding is that the precision of the best abundance measurements of both the Sun and other stars are in the neighborhood of a few percent for some elements and higher than that for others. Abundance measurements and uncertainties are typically quoted in logarithmic units of "dex" ([Lodders 2020](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1912/1912.00844.pdf)), and an uncertainty $\sigma_d$ given in dex translates to an uncertainty $\sigma_\%$ in percent of
$$\sigma_\%=\pm100\left(10^{\pm\sigma_d}-1\right)\%$$
Many of the measurements I can find in the literature for elements of the Sun and solar twins (e.g. [Nissen et al. 2015](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015A%26A...579A..52N/abstract)) approach $\sigma_d\sim0.01$ at best, which translates to $\sigma_\%\approx2.3\%$. Even with the rarest elements in the Sun, these uncertainties are substantially larger than the mass of a human body, and so our spectrographs would be unable to detect such a minute change.

It also stands to reason - and I'm handwaving here - that if our spectrographs can't make such precise measurements of the elements that do naturally exist in the Sun, they'd also be incapable of making adequately precise measurements of small amounts of elements that don't naturally exist in the Sun. Moreover, unless astronomers were looking for spectral signs of these unusual elements, they'd probably misinterpret them as being related to stronger signals if they even rose to detectable levels.

Comment: Re: "...the mass of a human body...", the querent says "*What volume of material would need to have gone into the star for us to detect it...*" so presumably even a significant fraction of a solar mass worth of human cadavers would be fine if it resulted in a long-lived detectable spectral anomaly in the star.

Answer (score 2):

## Frame Challenge - Wrong Kind of Megaproject

Stars are the element forges of the universe, during their life and after their death.  There's nothing you can add to one that won't be there eventually, and the stuff that isn't there initially will drop to the core pretty quickly without affecting the star's spectra.  Bodies certainly wouldn't - there's plenty of carbon in a star, and dropping a planetary mass's worth of human bodies into a star wouldn't appreciably change its behaviour.

But, if you were already committed to moving gigatonnes of material to a star, put it in orbit instead.  Have it block the light from the star in a mathematically predictable but unnatural pattern (like a series of primes, the usual "hello world" of interstellar communications).  This effectively turns the star into a giant signal beacon, and unlike a spectral thing, there will be no doubt about the nature of the structure.

After all, a star with a weird chemical makeup could have captured (and eaten) a planet.  A star that dims in a pattern commensurate with the first hundred prime numbers, on the other hand, is unambiguous.

Comment: To elaborate a bit on a point, the sun is about 330 000 times the mass of the Earth.  0.4% of that mass is carbon.  That's still a _thousand earth masses_ worth of carbon.  A billion of the honourable dead dumped into the star wouldn't even make a blip.  Stars are very big.

Comment: As far as I know Uranium doesn't occur in the visible atmosphere of any known star, or in fact form during it's main sequence life (nothing heavier than Iron does), so there are definitely elements that don't belong in a stellar atmosphere, I just don't know the persistence or signal magnitude. An artifact built around a star says "we are here" but it doesn't say "we were here" for very long if it needs any kind of maintenance. Also it is a purpose built beacon in the night not the coincidental product of a cultural practice or industrial malpractice.

Comment: @Ash - bodies don't naturally contain uranium, and your subsequent question was "elements that might be deliberately dumped into a star".  If you're trying to change your star's spectra, then you're well into "build a megastructure" realms.  Moreover, the sun contains 16 exatonnes of uranium.  It's in its core, not its atmosphere, and was there when the solar system formed, but it's there, and that's where uranium dumped into the sun would make its way as well.

Comment: It's (one of the reasons) that Sunshine's central thesis was so ridiculous.  All of Earth's uranium wouldn't "restart the sun", because you could drop Earth, uranium and all, into the sun, and it wouldn't even notice.

Comment: Most people have tiny traces of Uranium, and other less natural radioisotopes, in them. They're not *trying* to change the spectra, they are but that's not their aim, it's a consequence. Exactly, if you dump uranium into the upper atmosphere of a star it doesn't belong there it should be in the core where it can't be detected.

Comment: The traces of radioisotopes in _people_ are going to be comparable in concentration to the radioisotopes that appear in the atmosphere of a star from cosmic dust falling in.  Ultimately, HDE's answer is correct, and is best summed up by the "Stars are big" thing.  GrumpyYoungMan offers the solution - dump a Jupiter's worth of bodies in, and someone might notice.

Comment: Why is it that everyone thinks the payload in Sunshine is a conventional nuclear bomb? The characters quite clearly state that it is a matter fountain device designed to pull mass energy from the true vacuum, theoretically possible but not something we're going to build tomorrow by a long long way.